# LEGO remote control 8879 for 2016 Winter Train not working

Tags: remote-control, battery

I purchased parts 8879+8884+88000+88002 to power the new Winter Holiday Train.  Fresh out of the package the remote controller 8879 does not make contact with the positive end of the battery.

Thanks to [this post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/6354/708), I was able to make an adjustment to the controller so that contact could be made saving me a lot of time and headache. Is there an easy way to get the positive contacts to stick out further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, so I looked at the forums, but I couldn't solve it.

In fact it is a problem with the contact, so I put some aluminium foil (the same one from the kitchen) in the positive contacts, and it worked!!! Yeah, I used DuraCell...