# Remote for Holiday Train 10254 Unresponsive

Tags: trains, power-functions

[image: LEGO train malfunction]

The remote isn't lighting up to show it's transmitting. Can't get train to run when motor is connected to IR receiver. Tried connecting motor directly to battery and it runs, albeit at warp speed. Checked all channels on both receiver and remote to no avail. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible related solutions: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4870/lego-remote-controlled-cargo-train-not-working

Comment: I'd double check the batteries and their connections in the remote.  Since everything else is lighting up in an encouraging way that seems to be the most likely place of the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you've tried everything but changing the batteries. Make sure you are using three AAA (1.5v) batteries.